# Access localhost on iPad

Tags: macos, ipad, snow-leopard, network, safari

I want to access my web application on iPad for local testing (http://myMachine_Name). But here is the problem;

1. I am having a local copy on my Windows machine with a Weblogic server running and the app server requires a VPN connection
2. Is there any way by which I can access http://myMachine_Name on the iPad , and given that my local machine would be connected to VPN.
3. Is there any iPad app which can help in testing..My main purpose is to have the fastest way to test any changes I make on the iPad and that I think would be to directly access http://myMachine_Name on the iPad Safari. But I do not know how.

Note: By VPN, I mean it is connected to another network at a remote location. Also the iPad is connected to the internet via a Wifi connection on MAC which is on the same local network as my Windows machine..

I think having VPN connectivity on the iPad might be an option, but I'll want to avoid that as that would require paying huge licensing fee.

Please let me know if I need to provide any other clarifications..

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to access localhost on your iPad because you're not running a webserver on your iPad. I'm not sure if I understand the question, but it sounds like you are running the webserver on you Windows machine and you can access it on that machine at http://windows-pc-name.

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "the app server requires a VPN connection," but it sounds like you need to connect to the remote network in order to run the webapp. Generally all traffic is sent over VPN so that is probably why you can't visit http://windows-pc-name on your iPad's browser. I would see if you can configure your webserver to use VPN, and not have your Windows network connection go through VPN. That way the server can communicate with the remote network, but it won't interfere with anything else.

Just in case you are using the wrong name, try http://192.168.1.101 or whatever you Windows Machine's local IP address is.

Comment: Hi styfle.First of all, thank you for answering the question. Just to reiterate;
1. Yes, I am running a weblogic server on my windows machine and access it via http://windows-pc-name on that same machine.
2. Actually the weblogic (app server) requires VPN connection (though I  am not very sure, but think it is coz of some database which is only accessible via VPN)..I cannot access the web app on my Windows PC browser if I am not connected to the VPN  (i.e. the app server does not work)
Now I want to somehow access the same web app on my iPad.i.e.the http://windows-pc-name I access on Windows

Comment: The main issue is..since the Windows machine is on VPN, the iPad cannot access it (even though they are on the same LAN and indirectly connected via the same router)..I mean the iPad connects to the internet via a shared connection on a same local MAC.

Comment: I have not used weblogic before but can you configure it to use the VPN without configuring your whole machine to use VPN?

Comment: Have you tried to connect your iPad/Mac to the same VPN ?? - it should then be on the same network.

Comment: Another solution could be to find your public IP-adr. of the Windows PC. You can try to get the IP-adr. with this page: http://www.myipaddress.com/ - then try to see if you can get a connection from your iPad by using the found IP-adr.

Comment: ok..First I am not sure how exactly can I configure Weblogic ONLY to use the VPN and not the whole machine.

While I know connecting the iPad to the VPN might work, I am trying to avoid that as there seems to be a huge licensing fee to pay for that..

Also I'll have to try out the public ip thing..But let's say I can access my Windows m/c somehow using that..But can that actually mean that the web app can also be accessed via iPad Safari?

Comment: @Rene Larsen: So far your responses seem to be moving towards a workable solution. Thx. Please suggest something based on the comments above..

Comment: I don't think that you "just like that" can configure WebLogic to use the VPN - with only one net card. If this should work, you need minimum two net cards, so you can configure WebLogic on one using the VPN, and then use the other net card for "local" traffic (wired and wireless net cards could be a solution ??).

Comment: Hmm...that Weblogic config seems to be something very tough to implement..Is there any other way..I mean lets say the Windows machine is completely on VPN and now I want to access from iPad(without the VPN) ?

Comment: As I wrote - if you have two net cards on the machine running Weblogic (e.g. wired and wireless), then you should be able to use one card when connection via VPN, and then the other for LAN access, which your iPad then can connect to.

Comment: @hmthr Try disabling VPN. Just run the web server and host some arbitrary index.html page. Visit http://windows-pc-name-here and it should work on any machine connected to your local network, correct?

Comment: If I disable the VPN, I cannot access the web app even on my Windows machine (http://my_windows_machine)

Comment: @hmthr I looked up WebLogic again and I confused it for a web server when it is in fact an application server which I know nothing about. This question should probably be migrated to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

you can not access your local computer to the ipad because ipad runs in web service well if you connect computer and ipad both of them to internet then you can access through [ipad vpn](http://www.purevpn.com/vpn-service/ipad-vpn.php).